# XAML change size and display of horizontal scroll bar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to change the size and display of the horizontal scroll bar. Currently the scroll bar is displayed only when I move the listview items.
I need to make it bigger and add color to it. Can I use style for it plz.

```
 <ListView x:Name="listview" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourCollection}"
                  GotFocus="StackPanel_GotFocus" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" Margin="125,262,125,19">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="200"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="200" Width="256">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="144" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  Height="56" Width="256" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom style for your ListView and its internal ScrollViewer and ScrollBar.

You will find the definitions for the styles to override here:

- [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299137.aspx)
- [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299151.aspx)
- [ScrollBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299150.aspx)

If you want to change all the ScrollBars of your app, overriding [ScrollBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299150.aspx) style will be enough

If you want this custom style to apply only within your ListView, it will be more tricky.

You will have to create a custom ScrollBar style changing the properties you want.
Then create a custom ScrollViewer style which will reference/use your custom ScrollBar style.
And finally, create a custom ListView style which will reference/use your custom ScrollViewer style.

It will look as the following:

ListView style:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="MyListViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
               <Border>
                  <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Style={StaticResource myCustomScrollViewerStyle" />
               </Border>
           </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
</Style >
```

Scrollviewer style:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" x:Key="myCustomScrollViewerStyle">
    ...
    <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Style={StaticResource myCustomScrollBarStyle}" />
    <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" Style={StaticResource myCustomScrollBarStyle}" />
     ...
</Style>
```

Scrollbar style:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar" x:Key="myCustomScrollBarStyle">
     ...
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
     ...
</Style>
```